# What is this 4 sharp symbol and what does it mean?

Tags: notation, accidentals

I came across this symbol (unfortunately not in context — I was looking through some engraving font glyphs) that looks like a sharp with a 4 above it:

[image: Musical Sharp Symbol with 4 above it attached to the left vertical line]

What is this symbol called and what does it mean? If it's not a standalone symbol and instead is something composited, what context would it be used in?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the [list of musical symbols at Dolmetsch Online](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm), that is a quarter-tone sharp sign; it signifies that a pitch should be raised by a quarter-tone. There is an analogous quarter-tone flat symbol.

Comment: Indeed! Wikipedia's list only had the sharp with a single line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Quarter_tones Thanks!

Comment: I've tried playing it on piano, but it's not easy playing in the cracks!

Comment: @Tim you have to pull on the strings with your free hand :-)

Comment: @Tim Amateur singers are experts at producing these notes, though... ;-)

Comment: @Tim you need a second piano tuned by some 
"A=430" imbecile. Edit: nope; that gets us about 0.4 of a tone, not 0.25.

Comment: And a really bad one, I might add. If you play quarter-tone music of any length, such a large, busy symbol for a single alteration makes the score really hard to read. Luckily there are other quarter-tone symbols available.

Comment: At risk of sounding sacrilegeous but E-Pianos often come equipped with a pitch-bend-thingy

Comment: Hah! Saxophones bend by quarter and half tones all the time. Not always intentionally, I might add.

Comment: @cmaster I play trombone, and I produce them all the time. Have yet to see them printed though.

Comment: I've seen a piano (in a museum) with a third row of grey keys in between all the other keys for playing quarter-tones.  Sadly they won't let you play it.  I imagine it's very rare and extremely expensive.